# find where a program is running from command line

Tags: command-line, bash

How can I find where a program is running from? I tried using 
`which gclone` but it didn't show anything. For example, I want the command to return the location of the script or command.

Comment: The command is correct, the name of the program probably not. What software is that?

Comment: If script or command resides in any folders that are listed in PATH variable ( do  `echo $PATH` ) , then it will show up in output of `which` command. Otherwise, it won't and you have to find other ways. Also, shell built-in commands don't show up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
whereis gclone
```

or run gclone and do:

```
find . -perm /u+x -type f
```

to find it. the second command will find all the executables.

Answer (score 0):

I assume "gclone" is a script that you made ? The "which" command only shows programs or scripts that are in the PATH. You could copy your script in /usr/local/bin/ and then try again (Note that /usr/local/bin/ can be read by all users on that computer).  Can you try that ?